# How to format Excel cells to show duration in years and months?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't figure out how to do custom formatting that would format input "1/5" as "1 year, 5 months", or "5,0" as "5 years". I do want the cell to retain original input of "1/5" but visually display "1 year, 5 months".

Answer (score 2):

You could use a formula along these lines which splits the input based on the position of the `/` character:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("/", A1)-1) & " years, " & RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND("/", A1)) & " months"
```

assuming that a text value such as `1/5` is in cell A1.

Comment: Your answer is not addressing the Question,,, OP wants to apply `Cell Format` to cell has `1/5` or `5,0` to show `Years & Months` in that case how this Formula will works??

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this solution is flawed in the sense that it requires leading 0's for months and will only take input as yymm (without the / or ,), also it will not change the pluralization of years/months based on the number you have entered. Neither will it omit years or months if only one is entered.

Without further adiou however, here is my solution;

First select the cell(s) you wish to format.
Right-click and select "Format Cells...".
On the 'Number' tab select custom as your category.
Type the string below into the 'type' field.

> 00 "Year(s),"  00 "Month(s)"

You can change the quoted strings to anything you wish, as long as you retain the quotation marks.

To test, enter a few tests;

> If you enter 3445 you will get "34 Year(s), 45 Month(s)"
>   If you enter 45 you will get "00 Year(s), 45 Month(s)"
>   If you enter 405 you will get "04 Year(s), 05 Month(s)"

This has been tested in Excel 2010 and 2003.

Comment: it's not working as universal rule, suppose I write 35 then getting 0 years and 35 Moths instead of 3 Years and 5 months!!

Comment: Your Answer needs little correction it Should be `0 "Year(s)," 0 "Month(s)"` then works nicely!

Comment: @RajeshS I addressed that in my test cases. If you want to display 3 years 5 months, you must enter 305 instead of 35. I haven't tested it, but I believe your correction will make this not work for double-digit months, e.g. 12 should represent 00 years 12 months, not 1 years 2 months.

Comment: `"0 "Year(s)," 0 "Month(s)" ` returns 1 Year(s) , 2 Month(s) for 12. I've tested it. The right most value always represents Month. 202 will 20 year(s), 2 Month(s), but this `00 "Year(s)," 00 "Month(s)", returns 02 Year(s), 02 Month(s). ☺

Comment: You aren't understanding my point. How would you represent 0 years 12 months with your solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can use below formula to show numbers/decimal numbers as years/months. this formula wil work 2007 excel version or later version.

=INT(a1) & " years / " & INT((a1-INT(a1))*12) & " months"

Comment: Your answer is not addressing the Question,,, you want to apply Cell Format to cell has 1/5 or 5,0 to show Years & Months !!

Comment: If you actually try your formula, you will see that it produces the wrong answer for number of months.